# Using DJB's tcpclient or tcpcat bidirectionally

Tags: tcp, netcat

Can someone post an example on how to use DJB's tcpclient bidirectionally?

We need to read from Tor's ControlPort as well as write to Tor's ControlPort. A "file" that is open for both, reading and writing. This is not a Tor specific question but a certain example fo what we are trying to do.

I looked through the documentation but am unsure on how to accomplish this specifically.

- [The tcpclient program](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpclient.html)
- [The tcpcat program](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpcat.html)

At the moment netcat is used this way:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 9051 < "$OUT" > "$IN" &
```

This doesn't work with tcpcat:

```
tcpcat 127.0.0.1 9051 < "$OUT" > "$IN" &
```

How can tcpcat or tcpclient be used to do this?